# Utility class : EJB Session or Simple Object?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, pojo, stateless

I'm developing an EJB based application, in which I have the **JpaUtility** utility class. To implement it, I have two choices:

- Create a simple object JpaUtility, in which I put the getAll method
  static, to enable access from the class name (JpaUtility.getAll)

/* Simple Object utility */

```
public class JpaUtility
{
public static List<T> getAll(EntityManager manager, Class<T> clazz) {
        return manager.createQuery("...."); }
}
```

- Create an EJB-Session that contains the getAll method, then inject and use
  when needed.

/* EJB utility */

```
@Stateless
public class JpaUtility
{
@PersistentContext
private EntityManager manager;
public static List<T> findAll(Class<T> clazz) {
        return manager.createQuery("...."); }
}
```

**The question is: which one offers the best performance? Simple Object or EJB-Stateless? In other way, what does EJB offer compared to a simple object ?**

Comment: Have you tested either? You need to consider that you're going to be injecting the PersistenceContext into your code one way or another, so you'll need to determine whether the helper class is helpful from just a design perspective or performance perspective. Test both out and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish looks like 'Generic Pattern DAO', there're many "ready" implementations out there.One from AdamBien: ["Generic CRUD Service"](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/generic_crud_service_aka_dao)
More elaborate, eliminating the need for custom solution and approaching the simplicity of Spring templates from Apache DeltaSpike: [DeltaSpike Data module](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/data.html)

Now back to you original question, EJB or POJO, in your case, when working in an EE container the use of Entity manager, must be "container managed", so your "correct" options are EJB or CDI but not plain unmanaged POJO.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Why you said "correct" options?  (I agree with you, but how to argue this choice?)

Comment: If you used for example an unmanaged POJO then you should get the Entity Manager through an Entity Manager Factory, If you needed to associate this with a transactional context then extra work should be needed. EJB and CDI beans relieve you from this pain to write extra code that could possibly lead to more bugs.

Comment: The main advantage, from using EJB/CDI, is the given transaction context by the container. That is ok?

Comment: Just one, another for example with Stateless EJB is the thread per proxy pattern that offers thread safety, another is the automatic locking on Singleton methods and so on....